# in SQL Server, can i convert a column from being a varchar to an int datatype

Tags: sql-server, types

all of my data for existing records in this column are integers but the SQL server mgmt studio GUI doesn't seem to let me modify this column as it complains it has to drop and readd the table.

Is there any workaround to convert a columns from varchar(null) to an int field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name int
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a setting in SSMS.

Tools - Options - Designers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new int column
- Convert and copy the data from the old varchar column
- Drop the old varchar column
- Rename the new int column

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the column to an int datatype as long as there are no conflicts on the values in the column.

```
create table x(a varchar(10))
insert into x values ('1'),('2')

alter table x alter column a int
```

If there is a conflict you will get a n error in the trend of

```
create table x(a varchar(10))
insert into x values ('1'),('2'),('a'),('b')

alter table x alter column a int

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.
```